# Accounts created by using web3.eth.accounts.create() don't appear when web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)

Tags: web3js, accounts

I am new to Ethereum.

I am running a geth devnode.

Installed web3.

Used `web3.eth.accounts.create` function to create one account without any entropy and created another account by using the same command with entropy - for both these, I was given the address and private key for the accounts.

Then when I query `web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)`, the reply did not include the newly created accounts.

Any information on why these newly created accounts aren't listed?

On node command prompt, I did these:

```
Web3 = require('web3');
web3 = new Web3('localhost:8545');
web3.eth.accounts.create(); //this gave me the address and the private key for the first account
web3.eth.accounts.create("aaabbbb"); //this gave me the address and the private key for the 2nd account
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log); //the list this gives doesn't have the two accounts I created by the above steps
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: On node command prompt, I did these: 
Web3 = require('web3'); 
web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
web3.eth.accounts.create(); //this gave me the address and the private key for the first account

web3.eth.accounts.create("aaabbbb"); //this gave me the address and the private key for the 2nd account

web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log); //the list this gives doesn't have the two accounts I created by the above steps

Comment: Each one of those function calls should run asynchronously. Are you sure that you're waiting for them to complete? Also - you mentioned what the last function call doesn't return, but how about telling us what it **does** return?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was waiting for each command to return. The last command returned the addresses of the accounts I created soon after creating the geth node using the geth command personal.newAccount() on the geth prompt. The last command web3.eth.accounts did not return the 2 new addresses that were created by web3.eth.accounts.create([entropy])

Comment: Again - `did not return` is not what I asked. I asked what it **did** return. Not sure how else to explain this.

Comment: It returned 3 accounts that I created when I created the geth devnode

Comment: but not the accounts I have created by using the web3.eth.accounts.create function

Answer (score 1):

[web3.eth.getAccounts](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getaccounts) will only return a list of accounts controlled by node. Accounts created through [web3.eth.accounts.create](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#accounts-create)
will not be listed here.
for creating accounts on node using web3 use [web3.eth.personal.newAccount()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#personal-newaccount)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Calling web3.eth.personal.newAccount(<password>), seems to bring up the account created when I issue web3.eth.getAccounts. Does it mean the accounts I created by web3.eth.getAccounts can't be used in creating a transaction?

Comment: yes, account created with web3.eth.accounts.create can also be used to create transactions, but these accounts are ephemeral accounts, where as accounts created with web3.eth.personal.newAccount persists on node(stored locally on node).

Comment: Thank you. Using web3,  I did create a transaction with those accounts that created by web3.eth.accounts.create. When I try to send the transaction, I got : Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"invalid sender"}. In order to find out why that happened, I started looking at web3.eth.getAccounts. Any info on what I need to do in order to use the ephemeral accounts in a transaction? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you signed the transaction... post your code ... that will give a better context...